# Mysql Select with Dates and maybe Case when

Tags: mysql, sql, date

im having a problem where i cant think of a solution, maybe im having a bad table-structure or i just dont know enough about mysql select commands to think of a good solution. Maybe you can help me out:

So i got a table that has a Column with the Date-format (yyyy-mm-dd) i wanted to select all upcoming dates so i did:

```
SELECT * WHERE date >= now.
```

This worked kinda well but i also got "dates" where only the year is entered (2014-00-00) i also wanted to select these but "now" is already bigger so i made another column with the year only and if the month, date or both arent known i will use 0000-00-00 and the Column "year" now i could select like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE date >= now AND year >=now(year)
```

Now all entrys with 0000-00-00 wont be selected. If i use OR the entrys from last year will be shown.

So thats my problem, is there any way i can change my table so i can have entries with only the year or only year and month and of course all together? I already considered get rid of the date-format and use simple INT with seperated columns for year, month and date. But i think i will have the same problem.

Sometimes i just want to do a capsuled select like

```
SELECT * 
    WHERE (date >= now AND year >= now(year)) 
        OR date == "0000-00-00" (i know that this doesnt work)
```

Comment: And why is tagged php?

Comment: What? Sorry, but this is very confusing. Please show us an example data and what would you like to ahve for an output.

Comment: Your question is tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server], which are two competing RDBMS products (the former is a cross-platform open-source product, now owned by Oracle; the latter is a Windows-only closed-course product from Microsoft).  Which are you using?

Comment: im using php on the site so php could also help if possible. I deleted the sql-server tag

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you could use this request:

```
WHERE (date >= now OR year > now(year))
```

There is probably a simpler way though, that would preserve your design, like initializing at January 1st (01-01) instead of 00-00

Comment: This worked last year but now the "now" date is almost always smaller than the older entries so it just selects almost everything, with AND i can get the newer entries but not the ones with 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code:

```
 $_SESSION['month'] = //set here your selected month
 $_SESSION['year'] = //set here your selected year

 SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEPART(m,date) >= '".$_SESSION['month']."' AND DATEPART(yyyy,year) >= '".$_SESSION['year']."' AND date <> '0000-00-00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your table structure format. Actually just allow for that field to have `null` value when not entered. By default it will be `null` then. You shouldn't be storing `0000-00-00` as a value for `Date` type field. I would rather leave it as `null` , or as suggested in some of previous answers, initialize it with some other date. It would be much easier to manipulate with database then.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that half of you write is not MySQL and your database schema is terrible...

You have the following problems:

1. column data date does not have the date data type.
   To fix it, you need to add a cast to the select statement eg. cast(datecolumn as date)

   > select * from table where cast(datecolumn as date) >= '2014-01-10';
2. the way to use now date is using the now function.

   > select now(), date(now());
   >
   > > > result> 2014-01-10 11:11:36, 2014-01-10
   >
   > select * from table where cast(datecolumn as date) >= date(now());
3. Because your datecolumn is not a date (2014-00-00 is not a valid date), you need to use string manipulation to extract the year.

   > select substring('2014-01-01', 1,4)
   >
   > result> 2014
   >
   > select * from table where substring(datecolumn, 1,4) = year(now());
4. The comparassion operator is = and not ==
5. the select statement syntax looks like this (pay attention because you are missing the table in your statement)

   > select * from [Table] where [column] = condition ...
6. You probably need or instead of ands, therefore your query should look like this:

   > select * from FooTable where
   >
   > ```
   > cast(datecolumn as date) >= date(now()) 
   > or substring(datecolumn, 1,4) >= year(now()) 
   > or datecolumn = '0000-00-00'
   > ```
7. You should use something like phpmyAdmin or mySQL workbench to test your sql queries before try to use them on php, java or whatever is your programing language.